# Make lines with iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

How can I do this with iReport (using iReport v4.0)?
[image: Left image is what I've done -- and right image is what I want]

[Here is jrxml file](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=c4056de95d43c7d3&resid=C4056DE95D43C7D3!1176&parid=C4056DE95D43C7D3!147&authkey=!AMe5iIEKHk-Xj00)

Comment: You should post the screenshot of your `jrxml` file (the design in iReport)

Answer (score 0):

it depend on the size of Sub-report, check the sub-repot preview, if you want to increase the size of sub-rport in main report , for this you have to increase the size of sub-reportas where it is separately created.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using background band for those lines.
Maybe inside your parent report

Answer (score 0):

When you create a sub-report you can delete; Page Header, Column Header and Page Footer bands on your main report. After then, you can drag and drop sub-report icon on Summary part of your main report. You will probably use ColumnHeader and Detail bands on your Sub-Report. (It depends on your design. If you use subreports recursively, you can use again summary band.)  Later,you will select **Remove Report Margins** on your subreport. To get expected result; your subreport icon **Width** on main report should equal your subreport **page width**.

Answer (score 0):

Adding **borders** worked great for me. Expand your text element to cell size, right click -> Padding and Borders and add them all around. It's easier than having to handle draw lines. Less elements and faster editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add lines via the iReport `Designer` gui interface using the `Palette` (go to *Window* > *Palette*, then click *Line*, then drag it over to the Designer).

You can also add lines by modifying the `jrxml` code directly. I haven't found guidance in the [documentation](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation?version=61056) on this. But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15334907/3368818) answer to another question shows how to create a `vertical` line:

```
<line>
  <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1" height="30"/>
</line>
```

And it also shows how to create a `horizontal` line:

```
<line>
  <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="1"/>
</line>
```

Also, the **JRXML Sources and Jasper Files** [section](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v71/jrxml-sources-and-jasper-files-0) of the documentation has some more involved code such as the following, which uses a `direction` parameter with value `BottomUp` (there are also references to `TopDown` in the community [site](https://community.jaspersoft.com/) or [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer/resources)):

```
<line direction="BottomUp">
  <reportElement key="line" x="1" y="4" width="554" height="1"/>
</line>
```

And this, which uses `positionType` parameter of `FixRelativeToBottom`:

```
<line>
  <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="51" width="555" 
       height="1"/>
</line>
```