# How to draw vertical line in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using *iReport 3.5.2*? to design a report. I have a subreport where I need to have a table.

To build the table I have drawn horizontal lines for rows. However I am not finding any option to make the line vertical so that I can make the columns.

Could anyone please suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can make your line Vertical of Horizontal as you like
By changing `width` and `height` properties of the line
For example

If you want to draw a `Vertical Line`

```
<line>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1" height="30"/>
</line>
```

If you want to draw a `Horizontal Line`

```
<line>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="1"/>
</line>
```

Answer (score 1):

line is bad decision, may be problems on page ending/begining
use

```
<style name="cell">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
    </box>
</style>
```

for your textField/staticText

Answer (score 0):

Select line properties.Set width=1 ,height=value greater than 1